# Optimal parameters to minimize value from custom function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

Let's say I have an optimizer function looking something like this:

```
def optimizer(
    df_grouped,
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    weights: List[float],
    function: object,
    days: int,
    day_str: str, 
    df_all: pd.DataFrame
):
    all_scores = {}
    for i, df in enumerate(df_grouped):
        scores = my_func(df_day=df_day, df=df, weights=weights))

        all_scores[i] = scores
   
    avg_vals = np.mean([df_all.loc[key]["val1"] for key in all_scores], axis=0)
    truth_vals = df_all.loc[day_to_compare]["val1"]

    score = np.mean(abs(avg_vals - truth_vals), axis=0)

    return score
```

Basically, this function takes some arguments, do a bunch of stuff, and returns a single float, i.e. the `score`. In this case, `weights` and `days` are the stuff I want to optimize/find the best parameter values for.

`weights` are just a list of floats/initial guesses , e.g. `[1, 10, 30, 40]` and `days` are just a single `int`.

I have looked at the `scipy` `minimize` function, but it seems to be that all the arguments are subject to change (optimization) whereas in my case, I only need some of them to be optimized in order to minimize the score output from the function.

How do I go about that ?

Comment: i think you can provide arguments in the minimize function

Comment: Arh, so the initial guess `(x0)` of the minimize function are the stuff that it changes, while the `args` are unchanged ?

Comment: i think so, i am not sure. it must be in the documentation. I suppose if you provide it fixed args then it wouldnt change it right.